# Proof of higher order differentiation formula

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can one prove (maybe from first principle) the following formula used for higher order differentiation.

$$\dfrac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}=\frac{d}{dx} \left( \dfrac{dy}{dx}\right) $$

Comment: The RHS shows how you compute the second order derivative (i.e. by taking the derivative of the first order derivative); the LHS is simply the introduction of a shorthand notation for this. What do you want to prove?

Comment: Maybe this is simply per definition of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$?